# Calculating mean per genre without using libraries like pandas/numpy, etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, average, data-analysis

I'm a student of data analytics and learning Python. I've to do some code using pure python on a database to get summary statistics. Then I have to get summary statistics using numpy or pandas. Then compare the process of using pure python versus using libraries.

I've done must stats in pure python and fully completed in numpy - as the libraries make it so much easier. But, I'm stuck on one statistic using pure python.

Particularly how do i get an average figure of sales per genre. Picture of database attached to explain my query further.

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

This is what I have done using pandas and I want to achieve this in python without using any library

[image]

Comment: read the file in python, and store required in some data structure and calculate mean

Comment: Is your question about how to compute the average? Having a structure with the data, the averagin per genre should be somewhat straightforward, as long as you can correctly identify the genre for each entry. You could even make up lists with values for each genre, then take the mean.
In any case, show us some of what you've already tried in "pure" Python for solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Go for simplicity and use what you already know, use existing Python structures. You have a well formed csv file (or database, doesn't really matter), so use that to your advantage.

For each row, use the category as a key in a dictionary of arrays and add the sales value to an array.

Once you have iterated through all values, you end up with a dictionary of categories that allows you to compute the mean for each category. Is it the most efficient way of solving this? No, but it's a reasonable way of getting started and it might be just enough for what you are trying to achieve.